# Content download time inconsistent in the waterfall column in Chrome's network tab

Tags: javascript, java, api, google-chrome, performance-testing

What are the possible factors due to which the content download time is inconsistent which is shown in the waterfall column in Chrome's network tab

I am inspecting a api in the chromes network tab and trying to figure out the performance of that API. I have attached the screen shot of the network tab. 
Inside the waterfall column i can see the breakdown of the total time taken by that API.

Following is the break down result(which can be also seen in the attached screen shot) -

1. Waiting (TTFB) - 843.27 ms (This is the taken by my server to respond back to the browser)
2. Content Download - 11.23 secs **or** 1 sec **or** 3 secs or 8 secs

Each time I load the page and inspect this particular API, the waiting(ttfb) time is always consistent but the content download time varies. Also GZIP setting is enabled on the server due to which the API response size reduces to 243 KB from 693 KB.

I want to understand what are the possible reasons due to which the content download time varies each time i load the page and inspect that API.

Does it only depend on inconsistent internet speed or there are some other factors which affect the Content Download time ?

[image]

Comment: It should be the internet speed *and* the speed at which the server gives you the information. Each of these can vary, so you'd naturally be using the *lower* speed of each. If your download speed is 100kb/s but the server only gives you 80kb/s, then you'd be downloading at 80kb/s. And vice versa, if server is giving you 200kb/s you'd be capped to your download speed of 100kb/s. If you're on a shared connection and/or there are other bandwidth consumers currently, your download speed can vary second to second.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you for your detailed explanation. It solves the query that I was having related to the content download speed shown in the chrome network tab.